# Pointers in C: Allocating memory with value assignment VS allocating memory without value assignment

Tags: c, pointers

Char pointer's memory allocation via calloc works as expected only when I do not assign some value to the pointers.

I am trying to get some simple examples working to better my understanding of pointers / double pointers / triple pointers / ... . While writing the code for double pointers, I stumbled upon a really weird behavior.

```
#define PRINT(X, ...) printf("Address of " X "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__);

...
...

    int i = 0;
    char buf[12];
    char **two_star;

    two_star = calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i){
        two_star[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
        PRINT("two_star[%d]   = %p", i, two_star[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i){
        two_star[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
        snprintf(buf, 12, "pre_%d_suff", i);
        two_star[i] = buf;
        PRINT("two_star[%d]   = %p   two_star[%d]   = %s", i, two_star[i], i, two_star[i]);
    }
```

I get the following results for the above two for loops:

For Loop 1:

```
Address of two_star[0]   = 0xbcc090
Address of two_star[1]   = 0xbcc0b0
Address of two_star[2]   = 0xbcc0d0
Address of two_star[3]   = 0xbcc0f0
Address of two_star[4]   = 0xbcc110
Address of two_star[5]   = 0xbcc130
Address of two_star[6]   = 0xbcc150
Address of two_star[7]   = 0xbcc170
Address of two_star[8]   = 0xbcc190
Address of two_star[9]   = 0xbcc1b0
```

For Loop 2:

```
Address of two_star[0]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[0]   = pre_0_suff
Address of two_star[1]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[1]   = pre_1_suff
Address of two_star[2]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[2]   = pre_2_suff
Address of two_star[3]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[3]   = pre_3_suff
Address of two_star[4]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[4]   = pre_4_suff
Address of two_star[5]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[5]   = pre_5_suff
Address of two_star[6]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[6]   = pre_6_suff
Address of two_star[7]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[7]   = pre_7_suff
Address of two_star[8]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[8]   = pre_8_suff
Address of two_star[9]   = 0x7ffcd2238ab0   two_star[9]   = pre_9_suff
```

The issue here is evident. The pointers being allocated in the second for loop all have the same value of address. Meaning, that two_star[0] and two_star[9] end up being the same value as the same memory address ends up being updated again and again.

Comment: `memcpy` instead of `two_star[i] = buf;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strcpy(two_star[i], buf);` is insufficient.

```
    char buf[12];
    two_star[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    // snprintf(buf, 12, "pre_%d_suff", i);
    strcpy(two_star[i], buf);  // bad, trying to put 12 characters into 10
    two_star[i] = buf;
```

The destination is too small.

Instead, code could right size.

```
   int size_needed = snprintf(NULL, 0, "pre_%d_suff", i)  + 1;
   two_star[i] = malloc(size_needed);
   snprintf(two_star[i], size_needed, "pre_%d_suff", i);
```

---

Note: Error checking omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy): `strcpy(two_star[i], buf);` instead of `two_star[i] = buf;`, because in your case you don't copy string, just reassign pointer `two_star[i]` to `buf` (and here is also memory leak, because you've lost pointer to allocated memory).

Comment: This works. Will accept it as the correct answer when time permits.